# Tabela de configuração

Tags: c#, .net, banco-de-dados, nhibernate

Como eu poderia fazer para usar uma tabela de configuração no nHibernate? Ou seja, uma tabela de apenas um registro e que ele só controlasse esse registro, sei que tem como fazer isso via aplicação, mas queria saber se o nHibernate já tem algum recurso de trata isso automaticamente.

Comment: Sabe que pode votar em tudo no site também?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posso estar enganado porque faz tempo que não mexo com isto ou por não ter entendido a pergunta mas acho que não existe. Nem teria motivos para existir nada específico. Não é função do ORM ficar tratando desses detalhes. Claro que tem algumas coisas normais do *framework* que você pode usar para facilitar o acesso a esta tabela.  Em geral uma tabela assim é lida uma vez e colocada no cache.

Talvez seja melhor fazer uma tabela com pares de propriedade e valor. Pelo menos dá mais flexibilidade. É só uma ideia.